# How to change the shadow file manually?

Tags: shadow

I have a linux system and I create 20 users, after that I made a hash and import that into the shadow file instead of one of them(manually). *I do that because of some educational things* :)

```
user12:.rAuPMqtz7dZzHdfQMLJzum6vPYKJynmE29reN27MG/AsAHHt6a.1ZeyEkoo6xEJIzepKMyLai/:16607:0:99999:7:::
```

Then I saved the shadow and tested the user. It doesn't work. Why?
But it works when I used `passwd user12`.

Another problem is when I change the shadow manually (even one space or enter key) all of the users that I had can't connect via ssh. They see  `permission denied`. Why?

I copy-pasted the content of `shadow` and it doesn't work again. Why? Before I copied, it works. Just opening and saving it causes it to not work?

Comment: Not sure, maybe the file has to have specific permissions set? Maybe the manpage `man shadow` or its linked pages may help you...

Comment: thanks for your reply, I checked that it wasn't link to anything

Comment: How did you create the hashed password ? Ubuntu has a command `mkpasswd` , have you tried that ? For example, `mkpasswd --salt=hi foobar`

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't have a valid password hash:

```
user12:.rAuPMqtz7dZzHdfQMLJzum6vPYKJynmE29reN27MG/AsAHHt6a.1ZeyEkoo6xEJIzepKMyLai/:16607:0:99999:7:::
```

On Linux, the password-hashing algorithms are DES, MD5, SHA-256 and SHA-512 (see `man 3 crypt`, not counting [Blowfish](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1349252)), and the length of the password hash you have given doesn't match the lengths output by any of these (13, 22, 43 and 86 characters respectively, where yours is 75 characters long). and further, it doesn't have a salt or algorithm identifier. The system will try to read it as a DES-hashed value, with the first two characters being the salt - but who knows what password will match it then?

Comment: Thanks for your reply , actually I entered that here as a sample and it wasn't my hash.

Comment: @Sam Ah, but you have to give us representative output, or how do we know where the problem is?